# How do I insert a value into a Postgres DB column array at a specific position?

Tags: arrays, insert, postgresql-9.6

```
CREATE TABLE array_test (
  id serial primary key,
  data text[]
);

INSERT INTO array_test (data) VALUES
  ('{"one", "two"}');
```

-- Now I need to insert a second member of the array. My try would be the following, but the code only redefines the second member:

```
UPDATE array_test SET data[2] = 'three'
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: but the second member of array is two?.. so it updates it with new value - all as expected

Comment: Yes, it does update the array. I need to insert a value into it. For the result to be {"one", "three", "two"}

Comment: with auto shift? or for known array length?..

Comment: with auto shift would be ok

Comment: :D without it solution is obvious, with it will require a bit of coding, so if the length is defined - things will be much easier

Comment: I need to insert a value to a specific position, position 2. The rest of the elements should be shifted.

Comment: We can get the length with array_length(), but I don't understand, how it can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the existing array and append the new values to those slices:

```
update array_test
   set data = data[:1]||'three'::text||data[2:];
```

`data[:1]` selects everything up to the first element and `data[2:]` selects everything after (and including) the second element.

If you need this very often, it might make sense to put this into a function.

```
create or replace function array_set_at(p_data text[], p_pos int, p_element text)
  returns text[]
as
$$
  select p_data[:p_pos - 1]||p_element||p_data[p_pos:];
$$ 
language sql;
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
update array_test
   set data = array_set_at(data, 2, 'three');
```

Comment: Is there a similar elegant way to do the same with JSON?

Comment: @ИванЗавадский: not that I am aware off. JSON arrays are not as flexible as "native" arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I dont recal array function that would allow you auto shift, so here's some coding:

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
Time: 0.117 ms
t=#  with idx(v,t) as (values(2,'three'))
t-# , u as (select case when o > v then o+1 else o end, e from array_test,idx,unnest(data) with ordinality u(e,o) where id =1)
t-# , f as (select * from u union select * from idx)
t-# , r as (select array_agg(e order by o) from f)
t-# update array_test set data = array_agg
t-# from r
t-# where id =1;
UPDATE 1
Time: 0.635 ms
t=# select * from array_test;
 id |      data
----+-----------------
  1 | {one,two,three}
(1 row)

Time: 0.207 ms
t=# end;
COMMIT
Time: 0.874 ms
```

CTE `idx(v,t) as (values(2,'three'))` is your `[2]` and `three` - value for it